# Search functionality in room database

Tags: android, kotlin, search, mvvm

I want to create a search function for my user to quick access to my items .

Well , the first thing is that i have my product in a room table(List) and store them in database and show them with a recyclerview in the my main activity(Home activity ) .

So i want code a Query to search between them after user click on button search .

I code my query and after use it in my home activity nothing happend .i'm using mvvm model. pls help me with this .

Code :

My Table (List of Product ) :

```
@Entity(tableName = "cart")
data class RoomTables(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo val price: Int,
    @ColumnInfo val image: Int,
    @ColumnInfo var amount: Int

)
```

My dao :

```
    @Query ("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE title LIKE :search")
    fun searchItem (search : String?):List<RoomTables>
```

My Repository :

```
  fun searchItem(search :String) = db.GetDao().searchItem(search)
```

My Viewmodel :

```
    fun searchItem(search : String) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {


        repository.searchItem(search)


    }
```

And HomeActivity :

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



    lateinit var viewModelRoom: ViewModelRoom

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity)


        val list = ArrayList<RoomTables>()

        for (i in 0..20) {

            list.add(
                RoomTables(
                    null, "$i banana", 12,
                    R.drawable.bannana, 0
                )
            )

        }


        recycler_main.apply {

            layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@HomeActivity, 2)
            adapter = RecyclerAdapterMain(list, context)

        }

        val database = DataBaseRoom(this)
        val repositoryCart = RepositoryCart (database)
        val factoryRoom = FactoryRoom(repositoryCart)


        viewModelRoom = ViewModelRoom(repositoryCart)
        viewModelRoom = ViewModelProvider(this , factoryRoom ).get(ViewModelRoom::class.java)

        val editText : EditText = findViewById(R.id.edittextSearch)
        val searchbtn : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.search_main)

        searchbtn.setOnClickListener{

            viewModelRoom.searchItem(editText.text.toString())

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this approach.

First get list items from the table.

```
@Query ("SELECT * FROM cart")
fun searchItem():List<RoomTables>
```

Now from your repository.

```
fun searchItem() : List<RoomTables> = db.GetDao().searchItem()
```

In ViewModel.

```
fun searchItem(search : String): <List<RoomTables> {
    filterWithQuery(query)
    return filteredList
}
```

```
    private fun filterWithQuery(query: String, repository: YourRepository) {
        val filterList = ArrayList<RoomTables>()
        for (currentItem: RoomTables in repository.searchItem()) {
            val formatTitle: String = currentItem.title.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
            if (formatTitle.contains(query)) {
                filterList.add(currentItem)
            }
        }
        filteredList.value = filterList
    }
```

Make sure you add `Coroutines` above.

Now you have all elements filtered and returns new list items based on search query user entered.

In your fragment or activity observe data.

```
searchbtn.setOnClickListener{
    viewModel.searchItem(query).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { items -> { 
        // Add data to your recyclerview
    }
}
```

The flow and approach is correct and it is working, it is hard to follow your code since i'm not sure if the return types match because you are not using LiveData, in this case you must.

If you found confusing or hard to follow, i have a working example in github, compare and make changes.

https://github.com/RajashekarRaju/ProjectSubmission-GoogleDevelopers